# Ejemplo de NavBar fija y contraida en TOP

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

¿Alguien me puede hacer un ejemplo práctico a base de código de cómo hacer una navbar de estilo de estas que al hacer scroll hacia abajo quedan fijas en la parte superior tras hacer un efecto que se reducen en altura y cuando se vuelve a la parte superior vuelven a su tamaño original?

Es una especie de navbar fija y la navbar sticky de Bootstrap 4.

Estoy buscando algo como las navbar que aparecen en páginas como estás:

[Ejemplo de barra 01](https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/massive/index.html)

[Ejemplo de barra 02](https://www.miguelmanchego.com/)

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es algo como esto: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp En tu pregunta no has intentado nada, revisa el enlace que te comparto y nos comentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perdón por responder tras largo tiempo. Gracias por las aportaciones que me ayudaron y me mostraron hacia dónde enfocar la construcción del menú deseado.

Finalmente, con lo comentado y algún otro ejemplo que encontré llegue a montar la estructura de NAVBAR que quería.

Aquí queda para todo el que lo necesite. Incluso, dispone de una parte Responsive para pantallas de anchura máxima de 768px a falta de especificar casos de otras dimensiones.

HTML [index.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Barra de Menú :: Fija y Animada</title>

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        <div class="barra-responsive">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <h4>Menú</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <ul class="animated">
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="sec1"></section>
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Lorem aliquip quis ullamco</h1>
            <p>
                Mollit laborum nisi voluptate mollit ut proident deserunt nulla pariatur mollit occaecat cillum eiusmod eu. Officia commodo duis aliqua veniam consectetur. Laboris esse ex fugiat occaecat anim.
                Consequat minim dolore ipsum cupidatat sunt Lorem anim do incididunt proident sunt aute amet aliquip. Incididunt voluptate sunt voluptate sint irure cillum est est elit veniam tempor mollit enim. Esse eu veniam pariatur ipsum. Amet qui anim ea deserunt est aliqua aliqua occaecat elit veniam ullamco. Mollit id irure aliquip laborum laborum velit culpa deserunt amet ad eu. Ipsum id aliqua mollit voluptate. Labore fugiat exercitation excepteur excepteur occaecat duis consequat.
                <br><br>
                Culpa anim consequat minim occaecat cupidatat in quis esse. Ea mollit est veniam commodo culpa in laborum fugiat cupidatat reprehenderit nulla anim dolore et. Velit occaecat pariatur sit sit deserunt incididunt officia aute labore id sunt culpa. Ea ipsum occaecat aliquip reprehenderit proident nulla dolor esse do consectetur veniam nulla. In commodo excepteur id non cillum. Veniam nostrud do culpa sit cupidatat esse sit veniam sint excepteur Lorem sit.
                Aliqua consectetur veniam excepteur incididunt ad. Qui elit mollit qui dolore ipsum mollit. Anim eiusmod quis voluptate non sint cupidatat. Culpa consequat nostrud sit ipsum laboris irure proident esse. Excepteur mollit sunt labore amet esse nostrud nostrud Lorem commodo deserunt velit duis non. Cillum anim id nisi ex sunt consequat tempor tempor id incididunt sit.
            </p>
        </section>
        <section class="sec2"></section>
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Adipisicing sit ex esse</h1>
            <p>
                Mollit laborum nisi voluptate mollit ut proident deserunt nulla pariatur mollit occaecat cillum eiusmod eu. Officia commodo duis aliqua veniam consectetur. Laboris esse ex fugiat occaecat anim.
                Consequat minim dolore ipsum cupidatat sunt Lorem anim do incididunt proident sunt aute amet aliquip. Incididunt voluptate sunt voluptate sint irure cillum est est elit veniam tempor mollit enim. Esse eu veniam pariatur ipsum. Amet qui anim ea deserunt est aliqua aliqua occaecat elit veniam ullamco. Mollit id irure aliquip laborum laborum velit culpa deserunt amet ad eu. Ipsum id aliqua mollit voluptate. Labore fugiat exercitation excepteur excepteur occaecat duis consequat.
                <br><br>
                Culpa anim consequat minim occaecat cupidatat in quis esse. Ea mollit est veniam commodo culpa in laborum fugiat cupidatat reprehenderit nulla anim dolore et. Velit occaecat pariatur sit sit deserunt incididunt officia aute labore id sunt culpa. Ea ipsum occaecat aliquip reprehenderit proident nulla dolor esse do consectetur veniam nulla. In commodo excepteur id non cillum. Veniam nostrud do culpa sit cupidatat esse sit veniam sint excepteur Lorem sit.
                Aliqua consectetur veniam excepteur incididunt ad. Qui elit mollit qui dolore ipsum mollit. Anim eiusmod quis voluptate non sint cupidatat. Culpa consequat nostrud sit ipsum laboris irure proident esse. Excepteur mollit sunt labore amet esse nostrud nostrud Lorem commodo deserunt velit duis non. Cillum anim id nisi ex sunt consequat tempor tempor id incididunt sit.
            </p>
        </section>
        <section class="sec3"></section>
        <section class="sec4"></section>
        <section class="sec5"></section>

    </div><!-- /div #app -->

    <!-- jQuery, Bootstrap, ... -->
    <script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $('nav').addClass('estrechada');
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('estrechada');
            }
        });
        //Mostrando/Ocultando lista de enlaces de menú para casos de responsivo
        /*$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu h4').click(function() {
                $('nav ul').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });*/
        //************************************************************
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu h4').click(function() {
                //$('nav ul').toggleClass('active');
                //---------------------------------------------
                if ($('nav ul').hasClass('fadeIn')) {
                    // if the div has fadeIn class, remove it and add fadeOut
                    $('nav ul').toggleClass('fadeIn').toggleClass('fadeOut')
                }
                else if ($('nav ul').hasClass('fadeOut')) {
                    // if the div has fadeOut class, remove it and add fadeIn
                    $('nav ul').toggleClass('fadeOut').toggleClass('fadeIn')
                } else {
                    // if the div has neither of fadeIn nor fadeOut, add fadeIn class in
                    $('nav ul').toggleClass('fadeIn')
                };
            });
        });
        $(window).bind('resize', function() {
            console.log($(this).width())
            if($(this).width() > 768){
                $('nav ul').removeClass('animated').removeClass('fadeOut')
            }
            else {
                $('nav ul').addClass('animated')
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS [css/app.css]

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700);

/* :: PARTE PÚBLICA :: */

/* ********** Reset Styles ********** */

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* ********** Bootstrap Styles ********** */

/* ********** Estilos Propios ********** */

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav.estrechada {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}

nav .logo {
    float: left;
}

nav .logo img {
    height: 80px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav.estrechada .logo img {
    height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    /*misma medida que la asignada como altura al CSS de la IMG del logo*/
    color: #262626;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav.estrechada ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
    /*misma medida que la asignada como altura al CSS de la IMG del logo*/
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

section.sec1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../images/header-cielo-01.jpg?52aaab2203e2dca5be8142e603d77828);
    background-size: cover;
}

section.sec2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../images/header-cielo-02.jpg?8ea857ffda8c2ffa533a095e958a6330);
    background-size: cover;
}

section.sec3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../images/header-cielo-03.jpg?fbb4096c33a4b4c760892baaf3d5bdc0);
    background-size: cover;
}

section.content {
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: justify;
}

section.content h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

section.content p {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

/* ********** Parte Responsive ********** */

.barra-responsive {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .barra-responsive {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #262626;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .barra-responsive .logo img {
        float: left;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .barra-responsive .menu h4 {
        float: right;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        /*misma medida que la asignada como altura al CSS de la IMG del logo*/
        cursor: pointer;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    nav,
    nav.estrechada {
        background-color: #262626;
        height: 60px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    nav .logo {
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #262626;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    nav ul.active {
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px !important;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Aparte de las imágenes empleadas sacadas de Google (pueden emplearse otras en sustitución), se empleó la librería de jQuery para el efecto del Scroll, añadiendo/eliminando un CLASS al NAVBAR y la librería Animate.CSS para los efectos de `fadeIn` y `fadeOut` del MENÚ en el caso de una pantalla con un máximo de anchura de 768px.

Answer (score 1):

espero esto te pueda ayudar.

```
//JQuery en el HTML.
<script>
    $(function () {
      var $win = $(window);
      var $pos = 3;
      $win.scroll(function () {
        if ($win.scrollTop() <= $pos)
          $('.navbar').removeClass('navbarToScroll');
        else {
          $('.navbar').addClass('navbarToScroll');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//Código en CSS.
.navbarToScroll {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Te dejo documentación por si quieres leerla:
https://ekiketa.es/saber-la-posicion-del-scroll/

Si quieres sólo fijar el scroll como en el ejemplo 2 simplemente a la clase del navbar o el id le colocas esto:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
}
```